# HTTP web sockets Vs ActiveMQ web sockets

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic

http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html says that these guys have implemented stomp over web sockets functionality. How is it different for the normal web sockets solution provided by Dojo's cometd? I thought web socket spec defines its own message structure and all? How does the HTTP upgraded web socket differs from this stomp over websockets? Would really appreciate some expert opinion guys.

Thanks,
Bhanu

Comment: Still no answers !! ? :(

Comment: Web Sockets is not http, it uses a http handshake and then it doesn't use http, just wanted to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

The cometd implementation uses the Bayeux protocol, while the Apache implementation uses WebSockets.